# Delete row in gridview using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I wrote this code to delete rows from Gridview but its not working.

code in class.cs:

```
public bool bDeleteItem(int nItemID)
{ 
    bool flag = false;
    try
    {
        Training_sNairoukhEntities1 sNairoukhEntities1 = new Training_sNairoukhEntities1();
        IMS_Items oIMS_Items = sNairoukhEntities1.IMS_Items.Where(Entity => Entity.ItemID == nItemID).Single();
        sNairoukhEntities1.IMS_Items.Remove(oIMS_Items);
        int nResult = sNairoukhEntities1.SaveChanges();
        if (nResult > 0)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return flag;
}
```

code in Aspx.cs:

```
int nId = Convert.ToInt32(gvManageItem.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)]["ItemID"].ToString());
if (e.CommandName == "cmDelete")
{
    ManageItem oManageItem = new ManageItem();
    if (oManageItem.bDeleteItem(nId))
    {
        lblValidation.Text = "Delete is successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        lblValidation.Text = "isnt delete";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be, that you just forgot to call the SaveChanges() method of your database context?

Comment: @ClaudioP It's being called on this line: int nResult = sNairoukhEntities1.SaveChanges();

Comment: Have you debugged your code and checked the value of nId when delete is invoked?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose its Gives me all the data on the nid but the problem in nReuslt ==0 should be 1

Comment: do you use EntityFramework?

Comment: @lelma have you tried to use `DeleteObject` on your `context` instead of `Remove`?

Comment: No How ?? @stefankmitph

Comment: since i don't know what your `ObjectContext`is (but my guess: `Training_sNairoukhEntities1`... check if it is of type `ObjectContext`)... if it is: `Training_sNairoukhEntities1.DeleteObject(yourItem)`. but it doesn't take a List or IEnumerable... so you will have to do it in a loop.

Comment: i assume it did solve your problem?

Comment: would you mind if i post my comment as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Remove method "Marks the given entity as Deleted such that it will be deleted from the database when SaveChanges is called. **Note that the entity must exist in the context in some other state before this method is called**."
Below command will work:
sNairoukhEntities1.Entry(oIMS_Items).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
sNairoukhEntities1.SaveChanges();